# write data into excel dynamically in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

After executing a test case with multiple parameters I am passing the result (Pass/Fail) into an excel sheet. there are 6 rows the 1st result fail is entering into all the 6 rows (it should enter into only 1st row), the 2nd result pass is starting from 1st row and entering into all the 6 rows

Getting Data Code

```
public static Object[][] getData() throws IOException{

        int rowCount = ExcelUtil.getRowCount();
        int colCount = ExcelUtil.getColumnCount();

        Object[][] data = new Object[rowCount-1][colCount];

        for(int i=1; i<rowCount; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<colCount; j++)
            {
                //Check cell is empty or not
                if (data[i-1][j] == null) {
                    data[i-1][j] = "";
                }
                //change values to string
                data[i-1][j] = ExcelUtil.setCellDataToString(i, j);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Test Case

```
public static void signIn(String email, String password, String result) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        LoginPage lp = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);

        driver.navigate().to(loginUrl);

        lp.email().sendKeys(email);
        lp.password().sendKeys(password);
        lp.submitlogin().click();

        //Verify
        String expectedUrl = "http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=my-account";
        String actualUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        String loginmessage;

        if (expectedUrl.equalsIgnoreCase(actualUrl)) {
            loginmessage = "pass";
            lp.logout().click();
        }else {
            loginmessage ="fail";
        }

        ExcelUtil.writeIntoExcel(filePath, loginmessage);
    }
```

Writing into excel

```
public static void writeIntoExcel(String FilePath, String dataToWrite) throws IOException {
        int rowCount = ExcelUtil.getRowCount();
        int colCount = ExcelUtil.getColumnCount();

        try {
            for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
                shFile.getRow(i).createCell(colCount-1).setCellValue(dataToWrite); 
                fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
                wbFile.write(fileOut);
            }
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Data is not entered into excel");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are doing `FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(FilePath);` for every iteration of your loop, each time overwriting the previous file

Comment: Scary Wombat I removed the `FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(FilePath);` from loop then data is not passwing into excel, and no error is displaying only catch block is displaying

Comment: @prasad you should also move `fileOutput.close()` outside `for` loop. Also, show us updated code

Comment: Problem that I see is when you call `writeIntoExcel` from `signIn` then how do you make sure that it is going to the next row? Debug the code and put `i` on watch to see its value each time you hit `writeIntoExcel`

Comment: @Fenio I placed fileOutput.close() out side loop still no change

Comment: @prasad Update the code provided in the question so we can investigate further

Comment: @viki I debug the program and I saw that I value is increasing

Comment: @prasad `new FileOutputStream(filePath)` is still in `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

You should not be iterating rows for each test run. Change method

> public static void writeIntoExcel

to find row number based on email and password content and then create cells of result into that row.